# Convert jsx to tsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, transformation, porting

I have a library of React components with defined proptypes and am considering switching to Typescript. Is there any tool that will help port the code? Here is an example set of props for a simple component:

```
  static propTypes = {
    active: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    icon: Icon.propTypes.kind,
    tabIndex: PropTypes.number
  };
```

I'm imagining a tool that would convert this to something like:

```js
interface IButtonProps {
    active: boolean,
    children: node,
    disabled: boolean,
    icon: Icon,
    tabIndex: number
}
```

Not too hard to write, but it would be nice if it already existed.

Comment: What about a simple regex replace in your IDE of choice?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [react-javascript-to-typescript-transform](https://github.com/lyft/react-javascript-to-typescript-transform) package to automatically convert/port React JSX to Typescript TSX.

Code can be transformed via the CLI e.g.

```
react-js-to-ts reactFile.js
```

The following example is taken from the projects website. A standard react component e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
    prop1: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    prop2: React.PropTypes.number,
};
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { foo: 1, bar: 'str' };
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.foo}, {this.state.bar}, {this.state.baz}
        </div>
    );
}
onClick() {
    this.setState({ baz: 3 });
}
}
```

Would get converted to the following typescript file:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
prop1: string;
prop2?: number;
};

type MyComponentState = {
foo: number;
bar: string;
baz: number;
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { foo: 1, bar: 'str' };
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.foo}, {this.state.bar}, {this.state.baz}
        </div>
    );
}
onClick() {
    this.setState({ baz: 3 });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any tool that will help port the code

Nope. Either create one (and link back) or just do the manual work or just use `any` to get a quick start